# Python ThreadPool with limited task queue size

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

My problem is the following: I have a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` object with `worker_count` workers and a main `pqueue` from which I feed tasks to the pool.

The flow is as follows: There is a main loop that gets an item of `level` level from `pqueue` and submits it tot the pool using `apply_async`. When the item is processed, it generates items of `level + 1`. The problem is that the pool accepts all tasks and processes them in the order they were submitted.

More precisely, what is happening is that the `level 0` items are processed and each generates 100 `level 1` items that are retrieved immediately from `pqueue` and added to the pool, each `level 1` item produces 100 `level 2` items that are submitted to the pool, and so on, and the items are processed in an BFS manner.

I need to tell the pool to not accept more than `worker_count` items in order to give a chance of higher level to be retrieved from `pqueue` in order to process items in a DFS manner.

The current solution I came with is: for each submitted task, save the `AsyncResult` object in a `asyncres_list` list, and before retrieving items from `pqueue` I remove the items that were processed (if any), check if the length of the `asyncres_list` is lower than the number of threads in the pool every 0.5 seconds, and like that only `thread_number` items will be processed at the same time.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve this behaviour and I can't seem to find in the documentation some parameters to limit the maximum number of tasks that can be submitted to a pool.

Comment: Would probably help if you could post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code you have. It is easier to process and answer a question like that.

Comment: "change BFS to DFS" question seems different from "limit pool's task queue size"

Answer (score 3):

`ThreadPool` is a simple tool for a common task. If you want to manage the queue yourself, to get DFS behavior; you could implement the necessary functionality on top `threading` and `queue` modules directly.

To prevent scheduling the next root task until all tasks spawned by the current task are done ("DFS"-like order), you could [use `Queue.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import queue
import random
import threading
import time

def worker(q, multiplicity=5, maxlevel=3, lock=threading.Lock()):
    for task in iter(q.get, None):  # blocking get until None is received
        try:
            if len(task) < maxlevel:
                for i in range(multiplicity):
                    q.put(task + str(i))  # schedule the next level
            time.sleep(random.random())  # emulate some work
            with lock:
                print(task)
        finally:
            q.task_done()

worker_count = 2
q = queue.LifoQueue()
threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[q], daemon=True)
           for _ in range(worker_count)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for task in "01234":  # populate the first level
    q.put(task)
    q.join()  # block until all spawned tasks are done
for _ in threads:  # signal workers to quit
    q.put(None)
for t in threads:  # wait until workers exit
    t.join()
```

The code example is derived from the example in [the `queue` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join).

The task at each level spawns `multiplicity` direct child tasks that spawn their own subtasks until `maxlevel` is reached.

`None` is used to signal the workers that they should quit. `t.join()` is used to wait until threads exit gracefully. If the main thread is interrupted for any reason then the daemon threads are killed unless there are other non-daemon threads (you might want to provide SIGINT hanlder, to signal the workers to exit gracefully on `Ctrl+C` instead of just dying).

`queue.LifoQueue()` is used, to get "Last In First Out" order (it is approximate due to multiple threads).

The `maxsize` is not set because otherwise the workers may deadlock--you have to put the task somewhere anyway. `worker_count` background threads are running regardless of the task queue.

Comment: This is great. adding a concurrent.futures solution, but I enjoyed reading it.

Comment: How could I handle a KeyboardInterrupt and stop all threads?

Comment: @DavidDavó all threads are daemon threads in the example. They are cleaned up automatically when the script (main thread) ends. No manual action is required. You can handle KeyboardInterrupt like any other exception (try/except) or set your own signal handler for SIGINT signal (btw, it is mentioned in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

This other solution is nice. If you'd like more "easy" concurrency, especially trying to multi-task blocking interfaces (e.g. `requests`), the concurrent module is built in and may have what you want:

```
import concurrent.futures

def worker(num):
    print(f'in worker with {num}')
    return num*2

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed([executor.submit(worker, i) for i in range(10000)]):
        print(future.result())
```

Comment: It is unclear how it helps  with the BFS vs. DFS issue from question. `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` in the answer has the same issue as `ThreadPool.apply_async` from the question.

Comment: Fair. I'm putting it here as a faster alternative, but I really liked your answer for that reason