# Force Yapf to wrap lines after expression/just before for-loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, code-formatting, yapf

[`yapf` formatter](https://github.com/google/yapf) can wrap long lines in [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320445/4279) inside parentheses in the expression in the list comprehension:

```
threads = [threading.Thread(
    target=worker, args=[q], daemon=True) for _ in range(worker_count)]
```

I want to *wrap just before the `for`-loop* instead:

```
threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=[q], daemon=True)
           for _ in range(worker_count)]
```

`yapf --help-style` doesn't show anything obvious that can help here.

I can add `# yapf: disable` at the end of the line, to disable yapf. Is there some other way to force different formatting preference?

Current `yapf/style` settings:

```ini
[style]
based_on_style = pep8
column_limit = 89
```

Version:

```
>>> import yapf
>>> yapf.__version__
'0.13.2' # the latest on github
```